# ember get current component value

Tags: ember.js

I have a drag an drop layout component involved in my application. At the point user press save I want to get the component values in my controller and store them. (Im using Ember CLI) and don't know how to get component data into a controller. Have seen something like needs??

Controller application:

```
save: function(){
  var newName= this.store.createRecord('layout', {
    title: this.get('title')
  });

  newName.save();

  alert('saved');

  this.transitionToRoute('index');

}
```

Component:

```
 Setupgridster: function(){
    Ember.$(".gridster ul").gridster({
      widget_base_dimensions: [359, 232],
      widget_margins: [5, 5],
      helper: 'clone',
      resize: {
        enabled: true,
        max_size: [3, 3],
        min_size: [1, 1],
        stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {
          var widget_base_dimensions = this.serialize($widget)[0];
        }
      },
      serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
          return {
            col: wgd.col,
            row: wgd.row,
            size_x: wgd.size_x,
            size_y: wgd.size_y
          };
      }
    }).data('gridster');
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using your `ApplicationController`, you should use the JavaScript for your component (located at `app/components/your-component.js` if you are using Ember-CLI) to implement the save. This way the functionality for your component will be encapsulated by the component itself.

```
// app/components/your-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    showConfirmation: function() {
        var store = this.get('store');
        var newName = store.createRecord('layout', {
            title: this.get('title')
        });

        newName.save().then(function(newTaskSaved){
            alert('saved');        
        });            

        this.transitionToRoute('index');
    }
  }
});
```

And in your template you can pass in the title and the data store:

```
{{your-component title=title store=store}}
```